# Concatenating cell value based on duplicate values?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically my data (item number and it's associated dimensions) is like this in two columns:

```
FOX6215A     - Twin Dimensions (W x D x H): 38.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215A     - Full Dimensions (W x D x H): 53.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215A     - Queen Dimensions (W x D x H): 60.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215A     - King Dimensions (W x D x H): 76.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215B     - Twin Dimensions (W x D x H): 38.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215B     - Full Dimensions (W x D x H): 53.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215B     - Queen Dimensions (W x D x H): 60.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215B     - King Dimensions (W x D x H): 76.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215C     - Twin Dimensions (W x D x H): 38.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
FOX6215C     - Full Dimensions (W x D x H): 53.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
```

I need to concatenate the dimensions in column B (with line breaks separating each size) if column A has duplicate values. So the desired out come would be:

```
FOX6215A     - Twin Dimensions (W x D x H): 38.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
             - Full Dimensions (W x D x H): 53.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
             - Queen Dimensions (W x D x H): 60.6" x 1.3" x 59.8"
               ...
```

Because **FOX6215A** has multiple sizes. I'm completely stumped on how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel with TEXTJOIN():

Get a unique list of the item numbers then use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$10=D1,$B$1:$B$10,""))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Remember to enable `Wrap Text` on the output cells and size accordingly.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel:

Put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: That was it! Forgot it was an array formula, thank you so much! Very impressive!

Comment: Now you have a facsimile to the TEXTJOIN function, This will do just about everything that function will do, use it at your pleasure.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Will definitely be utilized in the future :)